# Old folder icon in Google Drive app on OS 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: macos, google-apps

Have this little problem, anyone knows how to fix it? Update the app didn't help. Tnx![image]

So, with the help of @John the solution finds me. Thanks again!
As for new icon I used [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/1586127-Dropbox-Google-Drive-Folders) from dribble. Hope this post helps someone else!

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you have some software installed to sync Google Drive? It would have changed the icon (just like the Dropbox app changes the Dropbox icon, though they've apparently updated it for Yosemite). You may be able to manually revert the icon to the default folder by right-clicking on the folder, choosing Get Info, clicking on the icon in the upper left of the new window and pressing Delete on your keyboard. That will just change it back to a default, though.

Comment: It helped, but only till I open the GD app again - it's turned back the old variant of folder icon. So it's maybe Google haven't update it yet, like Dropbox did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that Google Drive does not automatically update itself when you upgrade to Yosemite. I have just manually upgraded Drive (http://www.google.ca/drive/download/) and now, after a few minutes, it has automatically updated all of my icons.

Comment: Yeah! Great, it worked for me too, now it's the simplest way! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The folder icon is controlled by the app used to sync with Google Drive. Until the app is updated with a new icon, it will not change.

Comment: Thanks, I think that it's my problem, but it's really isn't.

Comment: Same goes for the status bar icon, it's not updated for Yosemite yet...

Comment: Still the same...

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can change it.  Right Click on the 'Google Drive' app in your Applications folder, select 'Show Package Contents'.  Navigate to ▸ Contents ▸ Resources ▸ lib ▸ python2.7 ▸ resources ▸ images.  There you will find a 'folder-mac.icns' image.  You can replace that image with your own Yosemite Google Folder icon image.

Comment: Until the app updates and then you have to re do this process again :\

Answer (score 1):

As someone has stated above, the main problem with this is that you'll have to change it every time the app updates, but you can resolve this making an automator workflow.

Automator-> File-> New

Look for "Run shell script"

Then configure it like this:
Shell: /bin/sh 
Pass input: to stdin

And the command should be something like:
cp new_icon_path default_icon_path

cp just copies some file to some place (or over another file, overwritting it)

default_icon_path: "/Applications/Google Drive.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/resources/images/folder-mac.icns"

new_icon_path: that's where you wanna keep the new version. It could be something like:
"/Users/your_username/new_icon.icns" (where you must substitute your_username for your own one)

So it would look like:
cp "/Users/John Doe/new_icon.icns" "/Applications/Google Drive.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/resources/images/folder-mac.icns"

Answer (score 1):

I've just borrowed from a few other people who made some code to solve this problem and created two simple scripts you can run to make life easy.

Steps:

1. Download the scripts: http://stuartbowness.com/scripts/Yosemite-icns.zip
2. Unzip them to your "Pictures" folder in your home folder
3. Open terminal and run:
4. bash ~/Pictures/Yosemite-icns/gdrive-replace.sh
5. bash ~/Pictures/Yosemite-icns/gdrive-inverse-fix.sh

This will:

1. gdrive-replace.sh - Replace all the crappy default icons Google has
   included and update them to nice icons that match Yosemite. It will
   restart both Google Drive and Finder when complete.
2. gdrive-inverse-fix.sh - Will fix the Google Drive menu icons when the menu bar is inverted to black (dark menu bar is enabled in
   System Preferences>General).